# MPI window allocation (MPI_Win_allocate) interface redundancy

Tags: c, interface, mpi

I am studying the interface of MPI (MPI-2 I think) and there is a function that I can't get right, namely, `MPI_Win_allocate`.

The interface is https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Win_allocate.html

`int MPI_Win_allocate(MPI_Aint size, int disp_unit, MPI_Info info, MPI_Comm comm, void *baseptr, MPI_Win *win)`

The function returns (creates) a new window `win` and returns pointer to the allocated memory `baseptr`. However, as far as I can tell, `baseptr` is redundant with the information that is already contained in `win`.

Is it really redundant? What is the use then?

In other words, is it always true in all cases that,

```
MPI_Win win;
void* baseptr;
MPI_Win_allocate(
    size, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, impl_, 
    &baseptr,
    &win
);

void* baseptr2;
MPI_Win_get_attr(impl_, MPI_WIN_BASE, &baseptr2, &flag);

assert(baseptr2 == baseptr);  // <---
```

Is this the correct use? is this design in place for performance? (e.g. `get_attr` takes a time/communication).

Comment: It seems to me that you are right (except it should be `&baseptr2` instead of `&base). The design makes perfect sense both in  terms of convenience and performance as you will always need this address.

Comment: Communicator and window attributes in MPI are locally cached values and accessing them is fast - there is no communication or computation involved besides a table lookup. As to why the API is designed that way, you should ask the authors of the RMA amendments in MPI-3.0, but as Zulan said, it makes perfect sense given that `MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE` is basically a convenience function that replaces the combination of `MPI_ALLOC_MEM` and `MPI_WIN_CREATE`.

Comment: I was part of the group that worked on RMA in MPI-3. The API allows users to get a pointer to window memory immediately rather than querying for it, which is tedious. The advantage of fusing MPI allow mem and MPI win create is that the implementation can allocate special memory collections, the way shmem_malloc does in OpenSHMEM.